# failing in result for left outer join c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to do a left outter join between two query and populate the result in new instance of object

this is the code for first query , which individually works fine, fetches the data

```
 var finances = _context.Finances
            .GroupBy(p => p.CustomerID)
            .Select(m => new 
            {
                CustomerID = m.Key,
                Debtor = m.Sum(p => p.Debtor),
                Creditor = m.Sum(p => p.Creditor),
            }).ToList();
```

and second query , which individually works fine, fetches the data

```
          var events = _context.Events
            .Include(p=>p.Customer)
            .Where(p=>p.Start.ToString().CompareTo(reqDate) >= 0)
            .Select(p => new 
            {
                CustomerID = p.CustomerID,
                FullName =p.Customer.FirstName + ' ' +p.Customer.LastName,
                End =p.End,
                Start = p.Start,                    
            }).ToList();
```

So the left outer join would be like this

```
          var qry = events.GroupJoin(
              finances,
              ev1 => ev1.CustomerID,
              fi1 => fi1.CustomerID,
              (f, bs) => new { events = f, finances = bs })
          .SelectMany(
              eventsFinances => eventsFinances.finances.DefaultIfEmpty(),
              (x, y) => new RequestEventsDto
              {
                  CustomerID=x.events.CustomerID,
                  Start = x.events.Start,
                  End = x.events.End,
                  FullName = x.events.FullName,
                  Debtor = y.Debtor,
                  Creditor = y.Creditor,
              });
```

the events table would populate the data but the finance table wouldn't ( which actuallu has data inside of it) and gives this error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

if I comment these two lines form finance table ,it works fine the rest

```
Debtor = y.Debtor,
Creditor = y.Creditor,
```

which part of the left outer join has a problem?

Comment: Does the `finances` list have any values? That's the only case I could see `y` being null in your SelectMany query.

Comment: should not be `y.finaces.Debtor`?

Comment: @AndrewH: Yes both finances abd events have value

Comment: Well, this really indicates that there are end results where `y` is `null`.

Comment: @GertArnold: but finances has value

Comment: Yes `finances` is not null, but there's no record for each `CustomerID`. Use `Debtor = y?.Debtor, Creditor = y?.Creditor` and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var var qry = from e in events
            join  f in finances on e.CustomerID equals f.CustomerID into fj
            from f in fj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {
                  CustomerID=e.CustomerID,
                  Start =e.Start,
                  End = e.End,
                  FullName = e.FullName,
                  Debtor = f.Debtor,
                  Creditor = f.Creditor
                 };
```

Comment: No it didn't wotk out

Comment: @nnmmss  " it didn't wotk out" - What is the error?

Comment: I defined two Dto classes for events and finance. so they have specific returning value not anonymous. and also changed  "from f in fj.DefaultIfEmpty()"  to "from ef in fj.DefaultIfEmpty()". then it worked. but I couldn't do it with lambda

Comment: @nnmmss Do you need the right code or you need lambda? In any case a compiler  will tranlate lambda back to the code you can see now and after this will translate to the set foreach and where operators

Comment: definitely I need the right code. but i was curious how it could be done in lambda to find out where my problem is. But any way thanks

Comment: I don't see how only a renamed range variable turns a non-working query into a working one. The query is nothing but a rewrite in query syntax, no idea how that should change anything.